# Luggage in European trains: limitations and check-in

Tags: trains, europe, regulations

Traveling between London-Paris-Switzerland. Do you carry your luggage all the way at your side (it's a lot)? And is there any limitation on the weight/size or, argh, extra fees for these?

Comment: Which train companies are you looking at? Eurostar? TGV? etc (I don't know all th European rain companies, just know they might have different rules)

Comment: @MarkMayo Technically TGV is a type of trains, not a company ;)

Comment: @Relaxed I can barely name the Aussie / NZ companies to be fair ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you generally have to carry your luggage with you, at your side in designated areas in your carriage. In fact, being able to carry your bags yourself is pretty much the only limitation.

Depending on the train, luggage storage space can be plentiful, at the entrance of the carriage and between the seats (e.g. long-distance trains in France or Germany) or limited to tiny overhead bins (e.g. many suburban trains in the Netherlands). Furthermore, some railway companies offer a separate porter or delivery service, at a surcharge.

With a few exceptions (Eurostar in particular), there is no formal check-in procedure during which your bags would be weighed and no widely publicised size limits. But I assume the respective terms and conditions associated with your ticket gives the operator the right to deny boarding if you have an unreasonable amount of luggage or somehow impede the comfort or safety of the other passengers.

In almost all cases, bicycles are specifically banned, at least if you don't have an extra ticket.

Finally, Eurostar, which you will take between London and Paris, [has more specific guidelines](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/travel-info/travel-planning/luggage/luggage-allowances):

> There is no luggage weight restriction on Eurostar – you just have to be able to carry your own bags onto the train.
>
> **Travelling on an adult ticket**
>
> - 2 pieces of luggage (up to 85cm long)
> - 1 piece of hand luggage
>
> […]
>
> If you arrive at the station with more than your luggage allowance and you haven’t booked it into our registered luggage service, you’ll either be charged an excess luggage fee or be asked to register your luggage before departure.